# What are the differences between Array and Matrix?

Tags: matlab

The official MATLAB documentation uses the terms **Array** and **Matrix** everywhere. And I cannot tell the differences between them. Could someone kindly explain to me? Thanks.

For example, the `zeros` and `ones` functions use the term **Array** in their description, while the `eye` and `magic` functions use the term **Matrix**. But for me, for an instance, what `zeros(3, 4)` and `eye(3, 4)` return are both matrices which size is 3x4.

And another example is the function `repmat`, which should mean "Repeat Matrix", but its description in the documentation is "Repeat copies of array".

Comment: There are not. Everything is a matrix in MATrix LABoratory, including single numbers. It is common in programming jargon, in general, to call a `Nx1` sized matrix an array, as in other programming languages that difference is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is a 2-dimensional array. Arrays can have more than two dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I think your answer is correct and brief.

Comment: and furthermore, a vector is a 1-dimensional array, is that correct?